# div hover background-color change?

Tags: css, html, hover

How can I make it act as if a line of div is anchor so when I hover on it it returns to red

### **CSS**

```
.e
{
    width:90px;
    border-right:1px solid #222;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    padding-left:2px;
    cursor:pointer;


}
.f .e
{
    background-color:#F9EDBE;

}
```

### **HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="e" >Company</div>
    <div class="e">Target</div>
    <div class="e" style="border-right:0px;">Person</div>
</div>         
<div class="f">
    <div class="e">Company</div>
    <div class="e">Target</div>
    <div class="e" style="border-right:0px;">Person</div>
</div>   
<div>
    <div class="e">Company</div>
    <div class="e">Targetaaa</div>
    <div class="e" style="border-right:0px;">Person</div>
</div>            
<div class="f"> 
    <div class="e">Company</div>
    <div class="e">Target</div>
    <div class="e" style="border-right:0px;">Person</div>
</div>
```

Comment: do u want to make all sub div of f to have a background color when hover the e div is that what you want

Answer (score 140, accepted):

```
.e:hover{
   background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 35):

if you want the color to change when you have simply add the `:hover` pseudo

```
div.e:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: there are three e div in a row. what i want is to be able to change all the row.not one "e" div.

Comment: @tfeseas in that case u can put the property on the parent div

Answer (score 4):

div hover background color change

Try like this:

```
.class_name:hover{
    background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.e {
    width:90px;
    border-right:1px solid #222;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    padding-left:2px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

e2:hover {
    background-color:red;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <div class="e e2" >Company</div>
    <div class="e e2">Target</div>
    <div class="e e2" style="border-right:0px;">Person</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```