# modify 2 x inner div tags using an outer div tag using only CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

```
<style>
.main_block{}
.main_block:hover{}
.heading{background-color:red}
.content{background-color:blue}
</style>
```

```
<div class="main_block">
<div class="heading">
New Product
</div><br>
<div class="content">
This is my new product
</div>
</div>
```

I want to change heading div to background-color:orange and content div to background-color:yellow whenever hovering over the main_block using only CSS

Comment: Welcome to SO! What you are looking for is the `:hover` selector which has been discussed before, check out these questions: ["How to use 'hover' in CSS"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905033/how-to-use-hover-in-css) or ["div hover background-color change?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266669/div-hover-background-color-change). Please do some research before posting a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Voila!

You need to start with the `main-block`, isolate its `:hover` state, then narrow by the child element- requiring one rule for each per below:

```css
.heading {
  background-color: red
}
.content {
  background-color: blue
}
.main_block:hover .heading {
  background-color: orange
}
.main_block:hover .content {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="main_block">
  <div class="heading">
    New Product
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="content">
    This is my new product
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot believe that it was that simple. Thanks for your help. Often the problems that seem to be the hardest have the simplest answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in LESS or SASS like so.

```
.main_block{
&:hover{
        .heading {
            background-color:orange;
        }
        .content {
            background-color:yellow;
        }
}
```

}